# Where is the rectangle matrix of dots on my display coming from?

Tags: laptop

I have a brand new ASUS VivoBook and at random times when using it I see pop-up/overlay that looks like a rectangle matrix of dots. See image, its near the bottom.

I am running Windows 10 with table mode off. It appears at different locations on the screen and any mouse movement closes it. I dont know if this is a hardware issue, notification, or bloatware potentially?

[image: Link to image]

Comment: If you can return it I would - I wouldn't care if it's hardware, or badly configured software - If they're willing to ship something that does that, I don't want to trust them anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is a hardware issue.

When you state this:

> I dont know if this is a hardware issue, notification, or bloatware potentially?

You are overthinking this. If something like this comes up on a machine that is brand new, return it to the seller for replacement. If they are unwilling to accept a return, contact the manufacturer to have them deal with this as a warranty repair.

And even if the machine is somehow out of warranty, still contact the manufacturer because defects like this often fall out of warranty and it’s a manufacturing defect that they can address no matter what.

But in general—in tech and in life in general—if you buy something as a new item and it acts up bizarrely like this, don’t try to fix it yourself. Just return it. Saves you headaches and wasted time, energy, effort and even money by just asserting your rights as a consumer.